# Input date value in SQL Server

Tags: date, sql-server-2005, sql-update, sql-server-express

I want to update my promotion table, like :

```
update [promotion]
set DateStart = '2016.06.24 08:00:00', 
    DateEnd = '2017.07.10 10:00:00',
    TimeStart1 = '2016.06.24 18:00:00',
    TimeEnd1 = '2017.10.10 12:00:00',
    TimeStart2 = '2016.10.02 411:00:00',
    TimeEnd2 = '2017.12.25 15:00:00'
where PromotionName='40%Off';
```

This causes an error message:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Can we input date in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
TimeStart2 = '2016.10.02 411:00:00'
```

You are trying to assign `411` to the hours field which can only hold `24` (or `12`, in the case of 12 hour timestamp).

Comment: @KozackLixeer Please mark as correct if this helped you solve your problem, thanks.